# Best way to obtain a secure connection using Python urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, security

Hope this will be an easy question for someone to answer. I'm in the process of programming an application in Python and part of the application uses an API to obtain a download link and then uses that link to download the corresponding server updates. Currently I'm accomplishing this using `urllib.request.urlopen()` at the moment and would like to do so securely. Therefore I'm wondering if just specifying `https` in the URL is enough or if I have to use the context parameter in addition?

The Python documentation is a bit vague in how it handles HTTPS requests but as I understand it right now specifying `https` in the URL  should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation for [urllib.request.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request), there is a reference to the [http.client.HTTPSConnection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPSConnection) class in regards to the context parameter. In the documentation for the HTTPSConnection class, there is a link for [security considerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl-security). In here it states:

> For client use, if you don’t have any special requirements for your security policy, it is highly recommended that you use the create_default_context() function to create your SSL context. It will load the system’s trusted CA certificates, enable certificate validation and hostname checking, and try to choose reasonably secure protocol and cipher settings.

Given that the documentation on `urllib.request.urlopen()` shows that context is an optional parameter, you probably don't HAVE to use it to make secure https connections, but given what the security considerations section says, I would use

```
ssl.create_default_context()
```

to generate the context just as good practice

```
urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.stackoverflow.com", context=ssl.create_default_context())
```

### EDIT

Upon reviewing the source code for `urllib.request.urlopen`, if you do not specify a context but you use an https url, it looks like it will provide a default context for you. If you don't provide a context to `urlopen()` it will call `build_opener()` and in THAT function's comments it states

> The opener will use several default handlers, including support
> for HTTP, FTP and when applicable HTTPS.

So the final answer is you should be fine with providing no context, all it should need is the url